# Is it possible to show the restart policy of a running Docker container?

Tags: docker

When I create containers I'm specifying a restart policy, but this is not shown in `docker ps`, and it doesn't appear any format string shows this either.

Does anyone know how to see the restart policy of a running container(s)?

Comment: Show restart policies of all running docker containers: `docker inspect --format "{{.HostConfig.RestartPolicy.Name}}, {{.Name}}, {{.Id}}" $(docker ps -qf status=running) | sort -t, -k1 |column -s, -t`

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using `docker inspect` which is `json` format and just need to query it.

Here is relevant output of docker inspect for a running container `zen_easley`. Note to change **container name** as suitable for your environment.

- `docker inspect zen_easley`

```
"HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": true,
```

You can just run the following command to get the same and its output.

```
$ docker inspect -f "{{ .HostConfig.RestartPolicy }}"  zen_easley
{no 0}
```

If you see `RestartPolicy` has two properties `Name, MaximumRetryCount` and **no, 0** are the values respectively in the above output

You may also get the individual property value, say `Name` by using below command, appending `.Name` to the above command:

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .HostConfig.RestartPolicy.Name }}"  zen_easley
no
```

Comment: Also good to know: It's also possible to update the restart policy of an existing container (after `docker run`) with, for example, `docker update --restart always zen_easley`.

Answer (score 32):

You can get this via `docker inspect`.

Just the policy name:

```
docker inspect --format '{{.HostConfig.RestartPolicy.Name}}' <container-id>
```

Or the entire policy (including e.g. max retry count):

```
docker inspect --format '{{json .HostConfig.RestartPolicy}}' <container-id>
```

Answer (score 11):

I did this little script to check all the containers and their policy:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#Script to check the restart policy of the containers

readarray -t CONTAINERS < <(docker ps -a | grep -v NAMES | awk '{print $NF}')

for item in "${CONTAINERS[@]}"; do

    #Hard-Bash way
    #data=$(docker inspect "${item}" | grep -A 1 RestartPolicy | awk -F '"' '{print $4}' | tail -n 1)

    #Docker-pr0 way
    data=$(docker inspect -f "{{ .HostConfig.RestartPolicy.Name }}" "${item}")

    echo "Container: ${item} / RestartPolicy: ${data}"
done
```

Hope it helps to somebody!

Answer (score 5):

For single line of the code:

```
docker ps|grep -v CON|awk '{print $1}'|while read line; do  docker inspect -f "{{ .HostConfig.RestartPolicy.Name }}" $line |xargs echo $line ;done
```

Answer (score 1):

Scripts provided in other answers did not work in zsh, so I slightly updated them to make this one-liner.

```
for i in `docker ps -a | grep -v NAMES | awk '{print $NF}'`; do echo -n "$i "; docker inspect -f "{{ .HostConfig.RestartPolicy.Name }}" "$i"; done;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I needed and just works, even in bash.