# In Docker for Windows, How do I prevent containers from automatically starting on the daemon start?

Tags: windows, docker, containers, reboot

Every time my Docker for Windows daemon boots up, it will spin up 7 different containers. I can go through and `docker kill <id>` each container.. I can spin up additional containers, do other stuff etc, and all is fine... until I reboot. Once I reboot the docker daemon, they all appear again, the exact same 7 containers.

Where can I go to flush them from being candidates to reboot automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe those containers have a restart policy which will make Docker to run them every-time it sees them absent?

You can [confirm it with a `docker inspect`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43108590/6309).

If you see them running, try, before killing them, to [`docker update` them](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/#update-a-containers-kernel-memory-constraints):

```
docker update --restart=no container1 container2 ...
```

Then reboot and see if those containers are still running.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!